# Convert Existing web application UI into responsive web application

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design

I have single page ajax web application. All HTML structure build dynamically through pure javascript or jQuery. Now i want to convert this existing web app to responsive application. I had searching on google but i can not get it specific flow to do this. I also see lots of css framework like bootstrap,foundation,etc. Is those help to get out from this? if yes then How? My target resolution is 800*600 to 1920*900.

Comment: There's no particular trick or workflow to this. All you need to do is pick a responsive CSS framework and reskin the web app with it, applying the appropriate classes as you go.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bootstrap, just include the files - CSS should be enough if you want just the responsiveness, or try [Initializr](http://www.initializr.com/) - get the right template and copy your existing code into it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also look into the FriendlyURLs feature in ASP: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingASPNETFriendlyUrlsCleanerURLsEasierRoutingAndMobileViewsForASPNETWebForms.aspx. This will let you create mobile versions of the pages in your site.

If this is not your goal and if you are OK with commercial software, you can try the RadPageLayout control from Telerik: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/page-layout-overview.html. Check it out here: http://demos.telerik.com/responsive-web-design-aspnet/.

Answer (score 0):

Responsive web applications can be created by using CSS media queries. Please find below helpful link http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-in-3-steps wich provides overview of responsive approach with screenshots and demo

Good Luck!

Comment: Pravin Vaichal@ please,can you explain me how can i restructure HTML in CSS Media query?

Comment: @Rickyrock 1) if you google you will find lot of good responsive website articles 2) basic steps like you may start with basic wireframe and designs how your app should look in desktop - tablet - mobile 3) accordingly you may set breakpoints as in given url above and set CSS for block elements (like header, menu, sidebar, main, footer ) etc

Answer (score 0):

Telerik offers yet another way to make your ASP.NET pages responsive via the PageLayout control http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/responsive-page-layout.aspx.
The following responsive web site is made with it: http://demos.telerik.com/responsive-web-design-aspnet/